# CGAL python bindings in 2023

Tags: python, installation, cgal

I'm new to CGAL. Do I understand correctly that the current recommendation for python bindings of CGAL is https://github.com/CGAL/cgal-swig-bindings/ ? It is not recommended to use the 5-year old https://pypi.org/project/cgal-bindings/ anymore, correct? Thank you.

I'm interested to try out CGAL in python. If it works well, I can start using C++.

Comment: In general, it's easy to recommend a version of a library that is still under active development and support over one that has not seen commits for 5 years (this is the old repo https://github.com/sciencectn/cgal-bindings) - is there a reason you're still considering the old version somehow?

Comment: Thank you @Grismar.  I found what I need now: https://pypi.org/project/cgal.
It was in PyPI less than two months ago.  I like the fact that I can `pip install cgal`.

I didn't want the 5-year-old code.  I just wasn't sure which one to use. Python Binding for CGAL seems to have a long history of projects come and go in the past twenty years.

Comment: If you no longer require an answer to your question, please close it or write a quick answer yourself and accept that, so that the question no longer appears as unanswered.

Comment: I still have to try it out. If it works, I'll endorse it and write into the answer below. Thanks for the comment.

Do you have experience with CGAL Python bindings? How was it?

Comment: There are new Python bindings, which are under active development; see https://bitbucket.org/taucgl/cgal-python-bindings/src/master/. As opposed to the old bindings (based on Swig), they are only for Python; they are more efficient and probably more broad. There are several ways to install them. They suppose to work on all platforms.

Comment: I marked it as read-only and deprecated: https://github.com/sciencectn/cgal-bindings